# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: t2cGetCharSet

Tags: java, oracle, driver

I am getting the following error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: t2cGetCharSet

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cGetCharSet(Native Method)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getCharSetIds(T2CConnection.java:2957)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:320)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:361)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:142)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:79)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:595)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:512)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
```

I have tried both ojdbc14.jar and classes12.jar.
The Oracle version used is 10 G.
Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please also show the relevant code.

Comment: maybe your ojdbc14 jar is out of date. Try updating it.

Comment: The code used is Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
dbCONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@cssm";
currentConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbCONNECTION, dbUSER_NAME, dbPASSWORD );
currentConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

Comment: can you please give me the link for new jar file to download